# What is "AoMeGl" texture used for?

Tags: texturing, shaders

I found some models that along with the standard color texture has a "AoMeGl" texture. My guess is that each color channel is used for different things, but I'm not sure what as I'm not very experienced with the different types of textures used in 3d modelling. Here is an example of such texture and the model the texture is used for with only the standard color texture (if that helps):

[image]

[image]

Comment: "AoMeGI", from the name, suggests that it encodes three different values in the three, RGB, channels.  Ao, probably associated with the red channel, is most likely ambient occlusion.  Me, likely blue channel, sounds like metallicity.  If Gl is "gee-ell" rather than "gee-ai", I would expect it to be "glow", emission.

Comment: @Nathan I'd bet Gl is glossiness (a.k.a. inverted roughness) instead.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Oh yeah, that's a better idea.

Comment: And metallicity is probably green, not blue.  (I dunno why, I just always intuit hue backwards...)